# After login getting too many redirects error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

Whenever I try to add a product to a wishlist I am redirected to a login page where I enter my credentials and after that it keeps reloading and this error appears.

Thereafter, when I return to home page and refresh I am logged in. But when I try to access a page directly which requires login, it works perfectly fine. This error has been appearing for sometime now, it was previously working fine.

**routes**:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function (){
    Route::get('/checkout','PageController@checkout')->name('checkout');
    Route::post('/coupon','PageController@coupon')->name('coupon.check');
    Route::post('/order', 'OrderController@store')->name('order.store');
    Route::post('/orderinfo', 'OrderInfoController@store')->name('orderinfo.store');
    Route::get('/invoice/{order}','PageController@invoice')->name('invoice');
    Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController');
    Route::get('/wishlist', 'WishlistController@index')->name('wishlist.index');
    Route::get('/wishlist/{product_id}/remove', 'WishlistController@remove')->name('wishlist.remove');
    Route::get('/wishlist/{product_id}', 'WishlistController@quick')->name('wishlist.quick');
    Route::resource('/review', 'ReviewController');
    Route::get('/orders', 'PageController@order')->name('orders');

    Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'],function () {
        Route::resource('/admin/products', 'ProductController');
        Route::resource('/admin/categories', 'CategoryController');
        Route::resource('/admin/subcategories', 'SubcategoryController');
        Route::resource('/admin/coupons', 'CouponController');
        Route::resource('/admin/taxes', 'TaxController');
        Route::resource('/admin/discounts', 'DiscountController');
        Route::get('/admin/index', 'PageController@admin')->name('admin.index');
        Route::post('/admin/ajax/category', 'PageController@ajax')->name('ajax.category');
        Route::resource('/admin/users', 'UserController');
        Route::resource('/admin/tracks', 'TrackController');
        Route::get('/order', 'OrderController@index')->name('order.index');
        Route::get('/order/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('order.show');

    });
});
Route::get('/product/{product}','PageController@product')->name('product.view');
Route::get('/','PageController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/about-us','PageController@about_us')->name('about_us');
Route::resource('/contact-us','ContactController');
Route::get('/shop','PageController@shop')->name('shop');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add');
Route::get('/cart{product}', 'CartController@quick')->name('cart.quick');
Route::get('/cart/show', 'CartController@show')->name('cart.show');
Route::patch('/cart/{product_id}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
Route::get('/cart/{product}/remove', 'CartController@remove')->name('cart.remove');
Route::get('/shop/filter/{subcategory_id}','PageController@filter')->name('filter.product');
Route::get('/shop/category/{category}','PageController@shop_2')->name('filter.categories');
```

**Login Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Category;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo;


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {

        $categories = Category::all();
        $cart_items = session()->get('cart');
        $sub_total = 0;
        if (!empty($cart_items)) {
            foreach ($cart_items as $item) {
                $sub_total = ($item['price'] * $item['quantity']) + $sub_total;
            }
        }

        return view('login', ['cart_items' => $cart_items, 'sub_total' => $sub_total,'categories'=>$categories]);

    }
}
```

**This is how I am sending get request and which gives error after login**:

```
<a class="add-wishlist" title="wishlist" href="{{route('wishlist.quick',$product->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
```

**Wishlist Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Helpers\helper;
use App\Product;
use App\Wishlist;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WishlistController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $categories= Category::all();
        $cart_items = helper::cart_data();
        $sub_total = helper::sub_total($cart_items);
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $wishlist = Wishlist::all()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
        $products = [];
        foreach ($wishlist as $list) {
            $products[] = Product::find($list->product_id);
        }
        return view('wishlist', ['wishlist' => $wishlist, 'products' => $products,'sub_total'=>$sub_total,'categories'=>$categories,'cart_items'=>$cart_items]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $check = Wishlist::all()->where('user_id', $user_id)->where('product_id', $request['product_id']);
        if ($check->isEmpty()) {
            Wishlist::create([
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'product_id' => $request['product_id']
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Wishlist $wishlist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Wishlist $wishlist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Wishlist $wishlist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Wishlist $wishlist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \App\Wishlist $wishlist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Wishlist $wishlist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Wishlist $wishlist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function remove(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        Wishlist::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('product_id', $request['product_id'])->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function quick($product_id)
    {
        //
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $check = Wishlist::all()->where('user_id', $user_id)->where('product_id', $product_id);
        if ($check->isEmpty()) {
            Wishlist::create([
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'product_id' => $product_id
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your entire `web.php` file? If yes, see that your route group isn't closed with `});`. If no, try to put the entire code in `web.php` here.

Comment: Also, details from `LoginController.php` might help.

Comment: Have you added @csrf to your form?

Comment: @dparoli I have added it

Comment: @UdoE. please check it out i have updated the question

Comment: @Broick, where do you want to redirect to after the login? Is it the homepage or the page that required the login?

Comment: @UdoE. Page that required login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, 419 error indicate an expired session. I notice you are using the session helper method `session()` inside `showLoginForm()`. You should be aware that if a user is logged out or his/her session expires then that user cannot access the data stored in that session as it will be wiped clean. Trying to access session data this way through `showLoginForm` is counter-intuitive as the user will most likely have been logged out or had an expired session before accessing the login form - except for the case where the user is accessing the login form for the first time. This could be a possible cause of the 419 errors.

You can remove the piece of code where you are trying to access the session data to any of your several controllers that require authentication. Then, you are sure that the user has a valid session before accessing session data.

However, to redirect users after a successful login Laravel uses either the `$redirectTo` variable or `redirectTo()` method of the LoginController. If the method is defined, it overrides the variable and if not, the variable is used.

From your LoginController, none of them is defined. Usually, the variable is set to redirect to the homepage - `$redirectTo = '/home'`. However, to meet your requirement of redirecting to the page that required the login, you must use the `redirectTo()` method.

You can achieve this by using the helper method `url()->previous()` within `LoginController.php` like this:

```
public static $previous;

public function showLoginForm() {
    self::$previous = url()->previous();
    // continue with your code.
}

public function redirectTo()
{
    return self::$previous;
}
```

notice that I store the previous url when i first show the login form. after a successful login, this url should be available for me to redirect to.

**UPDATE 1**:

The problem route

```
Route::get('/cart{product}', 'CartController@quick')->name('cart.quick');
```

has a problem. You are missing a forward slash after `/cart`. You should notice this issue when you look at the generated url in the link. The correct form should be

```
Route::get('/cart/{product}', 'CartController@quick')->name('cart.quick');
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Since the route `wishlist.quick` is going through the `auth` middleware, do not use `redirect()->back()` for going back to the same page after user action with that route.
This is because, with the `auth` middleware in place, `redirect()->back()` is not always pointing to same location.

For instance, an unauthenticated user accessing the `wishlist.quick` route will be redirected to the login page. If login is successful the request continues to `wishlist.quick` route. Now, try to guess where the `redirect()->back()` inside `WishlistController@quick` is pointing to. Right! Surprisingly, it is pointing to the login page. So now the authenticated user completes his/her request with `WishlistController@quick` and is directed to the login page **again**. The login controller detects the user is authenticated and redirects the user to wherever he/she is coming from - `WishlistController@quick`. Again, there is `redirect()->back()` sending the user back again to the login page. You see the infinite redirect loop clearly in this funny scenario.

**SOLUTION**:

Change the line

```
return redirect()->back();
```

to

```
return $this->index();
```

Since `WishlistController@quick` doesn't return a view of its own, `WishlistController@index` is the best place to return to. Infact, you have to make this change for all routes that pass through a middleware and redirects the user back.

**In other words, do not use `redirect()->back()` in a route that goes through middleware**, if you really mean to go back to the same page.

Comment: but then this error should be common for every page I access which requires login,why does this appears only when I try to access a specific page?

Comment: @Broick, from your update, please post the url generated by the route in the  `href` of your link. It will be very helpful

Comment: I have updated my route as you suggested and now the product gets added to wishlist and also I get logged in but still I get the error of too many redirects after logging in

Comment: Where do you log errors? Is it an **error** or **warning**? Do you use DebugBar? Is the error stalling the page? Remove the `previous()` redirect method I suggested to see if the error is cleared.

Comment: I haven't did any specific coding to store logs for now so I guess it gets stored automatically in storage/log. It is an error like this **This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Comment: Tried it, didn't help

Comment: Now that the 419 error is solved, can you rephrase your post title and question so it captures the new problem or you can post another question.  Still include the new `web.php` file, loginController and any other route controller that uses login. I and others here can give solution to your new issue.

Comment: @Broick, the updated post has a `store()` method as your wishlistController method. but `wishlist.quick` is pointing to `WishlistController@quick`. Can you provide the `quick()` method instead.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part you can check now I have updated my code

Comment: @Broick, just put the entire `WishlistController.php` file.  I will update my answer as soon as possible. By the way, `WishlistController@store` isn't defined in route.

Comment: You are very much welcomed @Broick. It was a nice programming exercise. :)

Comment: Interresting @UdoE.
But I am having the same error and I am not using redirect()->back() nor getting session data without checking if the session data exists.
When the session expired, I am redirecting to the login form. After logging I am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: By the way when I delete cookies, I am able to login without ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
Any idea I can login after session expired without needing to always delete cookies?

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with Laravel throwing a 419 error is because of a missing `@csrf` inside the form.

```
<form method="post" action="<some route>" >
@csrf
<input ...... />
</form>
```

If you are sending any data in a form, please ensure you have the above CSRF token.

If you do have this token, can you add the form in the main question?

Comment: I am sending a get request,does it also require csrf token? I have updated my question with that anchor tag I am using to send request please check it out

Comment: So, having looked further at your question now you have added more info I can see that the route you are using is 

```Route::get('/wishlist{product_id}', 'WishlistController@quick')->name('wishlist.quick');```

Is this the route you are using to add an item to the Wishlist? 

If so, as a Get Request, you can't add items, further more, I have noticed you are potentially missing a forward slash after the word wishlist

```/wishlist``` ```/``` ```{product_id}'```

Comment: I have updated my route as you suggested and now the product gets added to wishlist and also I get logged in but still I get the error of too many redirects after logging in

Comment: I'd you show me the WishlistController@quick method I might be able to help with the too many redirects, however, I can't see the method in the initial question so can't help.